# Is there any point getting an S rank in all story battles?

Tags: naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-2

I've recently played through all story battles in Ultimate Ninja Storm 2 a second time in order to unlock titles number 67 and 76 (as per [this FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/982706-naruto-shippuden-ultimate-ninja-storm-2/faqs/61061), see "Which name Shall I Use?").

While doing so, I've managed to get an S rating in all battles except for the very last one, where you fight an awakened [Killer Bee](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Killer_B). Since the AI is pretty brutal by this point and you are at a severe disadvantage, I haven't managed to get more than a B.

So is there any point to getting S on all story battles other than feeling good about yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to get an S rank on that final battle, and the answer to my question is no, getting an S rank on all battles doesn't serve any actual purpose.

I managed that final battle based on the advice found [over here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/982706-naruto-shippuden-ultimate-ninja-storm-2/answers?qid=232929), specifically:

> Kinda easy, dodge side to side while
>   he's attacking, when he's done, spam
>   chidori.
>
> If you're really stuck with low
>   health, go awakening mode, spam
>   triangle, circle and it will
>   insta-cast amaterasu lowering his
>   health by 1/4 of a bar each time.
>
> Don't worry about low health,
>   finishing in awakening mode is an
>   additional objective which you need to
>   do anyway to get the Viper Fang, and
>   you SHOULD get an S rank.

However, like many things on the internet, when someone makes something seem simple it is often not the case. What I did do is use the iron-kettle bento (which prevents your guard from being broken) and then I just blocked until I had an opening, hit him with chidori, rinsed and repeated. The only thing to look out for is Killer Bee's overhead smash attack that simply ignores your guard.

Comment: Well, I would've thought there might've been something special waiting for me at the end...